# How to get cell value based on column value in one step?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to retrieve date from a cell in Column C based on the name in Column A in the same row. The name comes from a name in another sheet. I need to create several fixed-value variables that will be used to calculate values for a report that is in a different sheet.

Here's what I have now for the example with the Date:

```
var report = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var areport = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();     
var agent = areport.getRange('B6').getValue(); // The name of the person
    
var datafile = SpreadsheetApp.openById("....");
var asheet = datafile.getSheetByName("Agent");
var startDate = new Date(asheet.getRange('C16').getValues()); // The date for the person
```

So, instead of that reference to C16, I need to retrieve different rows from column C based on the name that is in the report. Logically, it is like this:
getRange(Column C if Column A==agent)

I know that I can extract all data from the Agent sheet and then create 1-2 variables and filter down to the right cell. But I want to do that inside getRange, if possible, because it will greatly simplify my script and make it just five lines for the five variables I need to set to the fixed values in columns C,D,E,F,G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getDateInColumnCForNameInColumnA(name='Name20') {//default name for testing
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');//sheet name
  const shsr=2;//data start row
  const names=sh.getRange(shsr,1,sh.getLastRow()-shsr+1,1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0]});//names arrray flattened
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(sh.getRange(names.indexOf(name)+shsr,3).getA1Notation()), `Date for ${name}`); //display a1 notation of range for testing you can remove this if you wish
  return sh.getRange(names.indexOf(name)+shsr,3).getA1Notation();//return a1 notation of range
}
```

[image]

My Test Data:

```
COL1,COL3,COL2
Name1,14,Wed Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name2,15,Thu Jan 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name3,8,Fri Jan 03 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name4,6,Sat Jan 04 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name5,12,Sun Jan 05 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name6,8,Mon Jan 06 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name7,21,Tue Jan 07 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name8,13,Wed Jan 08 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name9,17,Thu Jan 09 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name10,13,Fri Jan 10 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name11,16,Sat Jan 11 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name12,4,Sun Jan 12 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name13,0,Mon Jan 13 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name14,2,Tue Jan 14 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name15,9,Wed Jan 15 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name16,19,Thu Jan 16 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name17,12,Fri Jan 17 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name18,18,Sat Jan 18 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name19,23,Sun Jan 19 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name20,22,Mon Jan 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name21,15,Tue Jan 21 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name22,2,Wed Jan 22 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name23,9,Thu Jan 23 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name24,4,Fri Jan 24 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
Name25,20,Sat Jan 25 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
```

Note: you could write it all in one line but it wouldn't be just one step and it would be difficult to read.